# upload data continuously

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC dialog based application that tracks data and displays it. A buffer is filled with data points and charted on real time or in quick way. Presently, this is happening
in the application layer. How can a DLL or library can fill the data and update it to the graph box in the application layer continuously?

Answer (score 1):

The dialog application can create a timer and use a OnTimer handler to periodically call the DLL / library function to retrieve any new data.  Or the dialog application can register itself with the DLL so the DLL knows how to post a Windows message or call a callback function in the dialog app, to notify the dialog that new data is available.

The option of having the DLL notify the application assumes that you have control over the DLL to add these operations to its interface.